# Matching URL of specific pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying match URLs like these:

```
something_with_underscore.png
something_with_underscore_mark.png
something_with_underscore_3600.png
something_with_underscore_10x10.png
something_with_underscore_10x10_mark.png
something_with_underscore_10x10_3600_mark.png
```

Using this regular expression:

```
(.+(?!(?:_[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(?:_[0-9]+)?(?:_mark)?\.(?:jpg|png|gif)))((?:_([0-9]+)x([0-9]+))?(?:_([0-9]+))?(_mark)?)\.(jpg|png|gif)
```

This is basically two parts, part one capturing the name:

```
(.+(?!(?:_[0-9]+x[0-9]+)?(?:_[0-9]+)?(?:_mark)?\.(?:jpg|png|gif)))
```

part two capturing "features":

```
((?:_([0-9]+)x([0-9]+))?(?:_([0-9]+))?(_mark)?)\.(jpg|png|gif)
```

I'm interested in capturing:

```
group 1: something_with_underscore
group 2: (everything after group 1)
group 3: (first integer 10 of 10x10 part)
group 4: (second integer 10 of 10x10 part)
group 5: (the integer 3600 or whatever it is - if is there)
group 6: _mark (if is there)
group 7: (png, jpg, gif)
```

I'm using negative lookahead with a pattern looking like the matching group to get the name of the file. I'm doing this to allow _ in the name-part of the url. This, however, fails. (if you can see another way of achieving this please do tell).

I think it has to do with the _ and . but I cannot seem to figure out how.

If for instance you remove the first _ from the expression the three last test cases will match correctly.

Comment: Do you need to create seven groups?

Comment: @Doug, what is important is that I match the URLs so that I can extract the information (some of witch is optional). I'm not sure why you ask about the seven groups - can you ask in a different way?

Comment: I'm wondering if you are trying to do a regex find and replace. If you are trying to do a replace using regex then my answer will not suffice.

Comment: I'm trying to extract a set of optional information from the URL/filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
(.+?)(_?([0-9]+)?x?([0-9]+)?_?([0-9]+)?(_mark)?\.(jpg|png|gif))
```

Comment: Cool, with a few modifications to the grouping, this works. Could you explain why the lazy match at the beginning `(.+?)` will match all of `something_with_underscore` and not just `s`?

Comment: With this modification `(.+?)(_?(?:([0-9]+)x([0-9]+))?_?([0-9]+)?(_mark)?)\.(jpg|png|gif)` it will match the groups in my question.

Comment: @Michael: it will match until it finds an underscore followed by a number or litteral mark, and if there're no matches it goes to the extension.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It is not that lazy after all. hehe

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?  It matches all your examples.

`([^\.]+)(([0-9]+x[0-9]+)?)((_3600)?)((_mark)?)(\.(jpg|png|gif))`

Comment: No, because if you look at the matching groups all except the extension goes into the first group `([^\.]+)`. You could move everything till the end and achieve the same.